# Baseboard heater and thermostat trouble!

Tags: heating

My baseboard heater in a bedroom quit working. I tried to replace it and the thermostat at the same time (both are 120v). Neither would work, so I tested my wires and this is what I got: ground to neutral- 121.7v, ground to hot- 121.7v, neutral to hot- .2

Comment: How are the wires connected at the panel?  Sounds like maybe it's supposed to be a 240 Volt circuit,  but both "hots" are fed from the same leg instead of opposite legs.  Call an Electrician to come have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be rather surprised if your electric baseboard is actually 120V - that's fairly uncommon. 240V is much more common, without a neutral in normal use (ground, L1 (black) L2 (white, which  should be taped/re-colored red, but often isn't) and 240V between L1 and L2.

Whether the heater is actually 120V or 240V, the circuit is clearly in error if there is only 0.2V between white and black.

Comment: That room is the only room that has a 120v heater, all of the others are 240v. I have always thought that the garage, family room behind garage and the bedroom above were added after the initial build. I also have two light switches that quit working downstairs and I believe this to have been about the same time. I am looking into them right now. If I cant figure this out I'll have to call an electrician.

Comment: If it's really supposed to be 120V, then you have an open neutral, which is getting fed through something (one of those lights, perhaps) to make it hot (an open neutral connected to noting should have no voltage, but as soon as a loat is connected from hot to neutral, the neutral becomes hot on the load side of the break/open spot.) Definitely needs sorting out.